# Post notification that user is using my application

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

If i have a facebook application with name "abc", how we post to facbook ticker that "user_name is using ABC" when a user uses my application.

i use graph api to post photos. but if i post same message as status to users wall like above sentence, facebook takes it as spam. Right ?

so how to tell user's friends that this user is using "abc" ? i saw when some people play games similar notification is shown in ticker.

how is it done?

Comment: FYI: Facebook generates these messages automatically when they think it’s appropriate – they call it “social discovery”. If and when this starts happening, depends on the number of active users, user feedback and other factors.

Answer (score 0):

This is not spamming unless you are literally spamming everyone's wall. As long as you are 
just posting a singe line of status "user_name is using ABC" once or twice a day, you are fine.

Here is link from facebook dev's docummentation to post status messages.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Further more, it is always recommended that you read policies yourself before implementing any api.
https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: There is no official documentation of limit on how many statuses an app can post on behalf of one user. Some have researched that its 500 posts in 10 minutes per user, but no one is sure about this. So, better safe then sorry.